# In 20 year's time he ..... his own business.( Will run - will be running- will have run ) what's the most appropriate tense here?

Tags: grammar

In 20 year's time he ..... his own business.( Will run - will be running- will have run ) what's the most appropriate tense here ?

Answer (score 1):

All three are possible, and they mean slightly different things. An aside -- I think that the apostrophe goes after the "s" in "years":

In twenty years' time, he will run his own business. (implies more or less that he will just be starting to run his own business twenty years in the future)

In twenty years' time, he will be running his own business. (implies that he will already have been running his own business for some time time twenty years from now).

In twenty years' time, he will have run his own business. (and possibly have retired! The future perfect describes action completed at a future time)

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/future-continuous-future-perfect